# Get overall average and average per 5 minutes on a Time Chart

Tags: splunk

I have a timechart which currently outputs the average value for every 5 minutes over a period of time for the field "SERVICE_TIME_TAKEN" using following query.

```
service=service1 | timechart span=5m avg(SERVICE_TIME_TAKEN) | fillnull
```

I want to add a second line on this same time chart which shows the overall average value. This would be a single value which draws a straight line on the chart.

If I make a separate query, I am able to get this single value using following query.

```
service=service1 | chart avg(SERVICE_TIME_TAKEN)
```

How can I combine these 2 queries to to show the data on a single time chart?

Tried the following but it only shows the line with the 5 min average.

```
service=service1 | timechart span=5m avg(SERVICE_TIME_TAKEN) as service_time | eventstats avg(SERVICE_TIME_TAKEN) as overall_service_time  | fillnull
```

This image depicts what I am looking for.
Orange line is the 5 mins average and blue line is the overall average.

[chart link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1gkh.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use eventstats first to get overall_service_time. This will add this field to every event. Next use timechart to get average values based on whatever span you want along with overall_service_time.

```
service=service1 
| fillnull value=0
| eventstats avg(SERVICE_TIME_TAKEN) as overall_service_time  
| timechart span=5m avg(SERVICE_TIME_TAKEN) as service_time, last(overall_service_time) as overall_service_time
```